# Retain HTML Entities When Parsing Markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I have exhausted my research and tried many methods to no effect and am hoping I'm overlooking some kind of simple solution:

I am using a Jekyll site to produce HTML files for e-mail and need to use HTML entities for special characters (such as em-dashes and smart quotes) in order to avoid improper symbol interpretation (the content-type/charset is at times stripped out of the e-mail head due to complexities I won't get into here.)

My problem is that parsing my Markdown appears to convert all of my written HTML entities into the special characters when output as HTML, and I am unable to escape with common methods. When I type `&rsquo;` into markdown to produce a right curly quote it is converted to the `’` symbol within my HTML (instead of retaining `&rsquo;` in my HTML). If I try to escape it with back-ticks it will not convert `&rsquo` in the HTML but it places it within `<code>` tags which cause it to render as `&rsquo;` and not `’`. Is there a way to retain typed-out HTML entities for special characters or -- even better -- convert special characters into to HTML entities (in the HTML) when parsed?

I am using the Kramdown markdown parser with Jekyll. I have even gone as far as specifying the `entity_output` option in Kramdown to `: as_input` without success. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Something like http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/ perhaps? (Might need some slight adjustments, because all the examples I see there or on the github page convert < and > as well - but it could be a starting point I suppose.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs state:

> ```
>     --entity-output ARG
>      Defines how entities are output
>
>      The possible values are :as_input (entities are output in the same
>      form as found in the input), :numeric (entities are output in numeric
>      form), :symbolic (entities are output in symbolic form if possible) or
>      :as_char (entities are output as characters if possible, only available
>      on Ruby 1.9).
>
>      Default: :as_char
>      Used by: HTML converter, kramdown converter
> ```

So lets try those options:

```
$ kramdown --version
1.11.1 
$ kramdown
&lsquo;foo&rsquo;
<p>‘foo’</p>
$ kramdown --entity-output=as_input
&lsquo;foo&rsquo;
<p>&lsquo;foo&rsquo;</p>
$ kramdown --entity-output=symbolic
&lsquo;foo&rsquo;
<p>&lsquo;foo&rsquo;</p>
$ kramdown --entity-output=numeric
&lsquo;foo&rsquo;
<p>&#8216;foo&#8217;</p>
$ kramdown --entity-output=as_char
&lsquo;foo&rsquo;
<p>‘foo’</p>
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

Notice that I have Kramdown version 1.11 and Ruby version 1.9. if you have earlier versions, then things may not work properly.

Comment: Thanks, trying again today the kramdown options for entity-output appear to be working as stated in the docs. May have been a typo, many thanks for confirming this is the right method!

Answer (score 5):

In your _config.yml you can configure kramdown to leave html entities as they are written in your code with :

```
kramdown:
  entity_output: :as_input
```

See [documentation](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/rdoc/Kramdown/Options.html).

Comment: Thanks, I think part of my issue may have been the second missing colon. Cheers!

Comment: This is not working for me as of writing. Even the `{::nomarkdown}` flag doesn't work: `{::nomarkdown}&#104;&#116;&#116;&#112;&#115;&#58;&#47;&#47;{:/}`.