# Kramdown use on CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, kramdown

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed kramdown. As I see here:

[Retain HTML Entities When Parsing Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355233/retain-html-entities-when-parsing-markdown?answertab=active#tab-top)

it seems that I can test kramdown directly in the CLI. If I write kramdown it prompt me for a text imput, but how I can "tell" to the CLI "ok I finish please convert into html"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to signal [end-of-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file). You normally do this with `Ctrl-D` at the start of a new line.